# Counterfeit Marvel House of M Comics?

Tags: marvel, house-of-m

I recently purchased the House of M story arc in TPB form off Amazon, but I'm a little confused.

There is an "M" logo that is made when all the issues are stacked together, but the logo is completed before the end of the set.

On "House of M"'s spine, MARVEL appears in white text on a red background. However, on the remaining issues MARVEL appears in red text on a white background.

I'm still new to all of this, and it was a gift for my boyfriend. Does this sound off to anyone? He's not a "collector" or anything, but I don't want to have bought him the wrong stuff.

Comment: If you provide us with a list of isbn's for the books you got, we can check to make sure the whole story is covered for him.

Comment: Also, a picture of the spines together would be nice.

Comment: I'll add a picture tonight just in case. I did search by ISBN's that were provided on the Wikipedia list.

Answer (score 9):

Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_M), these are the ISBNs of the TPBs that correctly form the "M" on the spine:

- 978-0785118121: House of M: Excalibur - Prelude
- 978-0785117216: House of M
- 978-0785118343: House of M: Incredible Hulk
- 978-0785119234: House of M: Fantastic Four / Iron Man
- 978-0785116639: House of M: Uncanny X-Men
- 978-0785118114: House of M: Mutopia X
- 978-0785119418: House of M: New X-Men
- 978-0785117537: House of M: Spider-Man
- 978-0785119227: House of M: World of M, Featuring Wolverine
- 978-0785127505: House of M: Avengers
- 978-0785133803: House of M: Civil War
- 978-0785141662: House of M: Masters of Evil

You may have picked up a second printing of something, but "counterfeit" TPBs are pretty much unheard of.

Comment: Those are the same ISBN's I used to find what I was looking for on Amazon. I guess I'll have to check when I get home from work.  

The main reason I had any concern was due to one of the cover's was not as long as the pages and a plastic film on top had warped. Also the Hulk copy came with the pages tightly bound but were detached from the cover which just made me all kinds of confused - easily solved by returning, but just made me wary of the "M" logo not matching up and the "MARVEL" logo being different colors on the spine.